# Out of memory exception in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, windbg

I'm trying to figure out why do we get Out of memory exception in our WCF services process. The purpose of the service is to get the data from the database, format it and write to Sharepoint. The users execute multiple jobs like this simultaneously (we create a separate AppDomain for each job).

I used WinDbg to analyze the dump file(s) and see that at least in one of the App domains contains multiple (about 200) dynamic modules (assemblies). I did a DumpModule command on one of those dynamic modules and here is what I get:

```
Name:       Unknown Module
Attributes: Reflection 
Assembly:   18c1cbf8
LoaderHeap:              00000000
TypeDefToMethodTableMap: 1dd6eafc
TypeRefToMethodTableMap: 1dd6eb10
MethodDefToDescMap:      1dd6eb24
FieldDefToDescMap:       1dd6eb4c
MemberRefToDescMap:      00000000
FileReferencesMap:       1dd6eb9c
AssemblyReferencesMap:   1dd6ebb0
```

There is not MetaData start address as found for the PEFile(s), so I wonder if there is a way to determine what these dynamic modules contain.

Comment: This isn't enough information to be able to provide a clear and definitive answer, but since you denoted that your app is heavily accessing a database, then your issue is likely related to that. Ensure all connections are being disposed and make sure queries aren't pulling too much data

Comment: It will also help to look at the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Is it possible to attach a memory profiler? That should highlight the problem pretty quickly with a couple of snapshots.

Comment: Daniel, actually my question is really regarding how to decipher data in the Windbg and its extensions, SOS, SOSEX. The stack trace is not very helpful.

Comment: There are the commands `DumpDomain` and `DumpAssembly` which might help you. I also see the `Attributes: Reflection`, so these dynamic modules may be been created by `Reflection.Emit`

Comment: Stab in the dark and not an answer to your question directly but XMLserialization can generate lots of runtime assemblies see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2013/10/22/case-study-outofmemory-exception-caused-by-xmlserializer-is-not-used-properly/